# Is there an opposite of keyword this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Is there a keyword that is opposite to the keyword `this`?

```
    $('.lt-buttonContainer button').click(function () {

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass("button1Clicked");
        $!this.removeClass("button1Clicked"); 
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean opposite? You want all the others it did not select?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are referring to by opposite? I don't see what the opposite of this would even be...

Comment: Opposite of `this` here means all DOM elements except this button. Is that what you want? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a keyword that is the opposite of `this` in your context.

`!this` simply takes the logical not of the value of `this` which will not solve the problem in your code.

---

Your question could really stand for some clarification, but in your specific example, if you want all elements that were in the original collection, but are not the current value of `this` and that' what you meant by opposite, then you have to compute that collection yourself.

That could be accomplished like this:

```
$('.lt-buttonContainer button').click(function () {

    $('.lt-buttonContainer button').removeClass("button1Clicked"); 
    $(this).addClass("button1Clicked");
});
```

---

Or, if you really want a collection of the elements in the original collection that are not `this`, then you can do this:

```
$('.lt-buttonContainer button').click(function () {

    $('.lt-buttonContainer button').not(this).removeClass("button1Clicked"); 
    $(this).addClass("button1Clicked");
});
```

though the extra `.not()` operation in this second code snippet is not required in this specific case because it does no harm to `.removeClass()` from all objects in the collection before adding it back on one.

Comment: Well your first version of your question was sure crappy. Maybe the downvote came before all your edits.

Comment: @epascarello - it was not more crappy than the wording of the question <grin>.  Sometimes answers are progressive discovery of what the poorly written question actually means.

Comment: It was me, Still think down vote was correct but I didn't apply it. Because the important part of answer is the solution, and your solution can't help. We and also the one who asked all know that `!this` is incorrect. We are just looking for something to replace it

Comment: @jfriend00 and also the down vote and my previous comment written before your edit. Now everything is ok ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in method to get all the other elements. Use `not()` to remove it from the collection.

```
var buttons = $('.lt-buttonContainer button');
buttons.click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.addClass("button1Clicked");
    buttons.not($this).removeClass("button1Clicked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does following snippet help ?

```
  $('.lt-buttonContainer button').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $('.lt-buttonContainer button').removeClass ("button1Clicked");
    $this.addClass("button1Clicked");
})
```

Comment: Yes, so I take it there is not a 'keyword' I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) jq method and delegate event using following logic:

```
$('.lt-buttonContainer').on('click', 'button:not(.button1Clicked)', function (e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).find('button.button1Clicked').add(this).toggleClass("button1Clicked");
});
```

And if elements `button` are siblings:

```
$('.lt-buttonContainer').on('click', 'button:not(.button1Clicked)', function () {
    $(this).siblings('button.button1Clicked').add(this).toggleClass("button1Clicked");
});
```